# modbus-tk getting Modbus Error: Exception code = 3

Tags: python, modbus, modbus-tk

I am trying to use `modbus-tk` to serially communicate with a device via Modbus RTU over a RS-485 network.

To understand how to use `modbus-tk`, I am trying to query:

- Input register: `Year of Manufacture`
- Register address: `0x7543 = 30019`
- Device: `1`
- Data type: 16-bit integer
- Value = `2019` (verified using a [free master modbus simulator](http://en.radzio.dxp.pl/modbus-master-simulator/)).

[image: Year of Manufacture Register]

Here is the code I use, based primarily on [rtumaster_example.py](https://github.com/ljean/modbus-tk/blob/master/examples/rtumaster_example.py). 
 Input:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3


import time
from collections import namedtuple
from logging import Logger

from serial import Serial
from modbus_tk import modbus_rtu
import modbus_tk.defines as cst  # cst = constants
from modbus_tk.utils import create_logger


PORT = "COM3"
SLAVE_NUM = 1
MODBUS_MASTER_TIMEOUT_SEC = 5.0

ModbusReg = namedtuple("ModbusInputRegister", ["name", "block_type", "address"])

year_of_manuf = ModbusReg(
    "year of manufacture", cst.HOLDING_REGISTERS, 18
)  # 0x7543 = 30019


logger = create_logger(name="console")  # type: Logger
serial_ = Serial(PORT)
modbus_master = modbus_rtu.RtuMaster(serial_)
modbus_master.set_timeout(MODBUS_MASTER_TIMEOUT_SEC)
modbus_master.set_verbose(True)
time.sleep(2)  # Per https://github.com/ljean/modbus-tk/issues/73#issuecomment-284800980

logger.info(
    modbus_master.execute(
        slave=SLAVE_NUM,
        function_code=cst.READ_INPUT_REGISTERS,
        starting_address=year_of_manuf.address,
    )
)
```

Output:

```py
2020-01-21 10:38:09,031 INFO    modbus_rtu.__init__     MainThread      RtuMaster COM3 is opened
2020-01-21 10:38:11,048 DEBUG   modbus.execute  MainThread      -> 1-4-0-18-0-0-80-15
2020-01-21 10:38:11,077 DEBUG   modbus.execute  MainThread      <- 1-132-3-3-1
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModbusError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-9afaebcf3a35> in <module>
      7     slave=SLAVE_NUM,
      8     function_code=cst.READ_INPUT_REGISTERS,
----> 9     starting_address=year_of_manuf.address,
     10 )

c:\path\to\venv\lib\site-packages\modbus_tk\utils.py in new(*args, **kwargs)
     37             ret = fcn(*args, **kwargs)
     38         except Exception as excpt:
---> 39             raise excpt
     40         finally:
     41             if threadsafe:

c:\path\to\venv\lib\site-packages\modbus_tk\utils.py in new(*args, **kwargs)
     35             lock.acquire()
     36         try:
---> 37             ret = fcn(*args, **kwargs)
     38         except Exception as excpt:
     39             raise excpt

c:\path\to\venv\lib\site-packages\modbus_tk\modbus.py in execute(self, slave, function_code, starting_address, quantity_of_x, output_value, data_format, expected_length)
    312                 # the slave has returned an error
    313                 exception_code = byte_2
--> 314                 raise ModbusError(exception_code)
    315             else:
    316                 if is_read_function:

ModbusError: Modbus Error: Exception code = 3
```

It looks like this exception is for if `the slave has returned an error`

What do you think I am doing wrong?  I am new to this library.

---

**What I Have Read**

- [Can't connect to slave with Python's modbus_tk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37720022/cant-connect-to-slave-with-pythons-modbus-tk), I am using `pyserial >= 3.1`
- And every other question under the `modbus-tk` tag, some posts in the Google Groups, and the repo's examples + `README.md`

**Device Specifics**

- Device: SST Sensing's [OXY-LC-485](https://www.sstsensing.com/product/oxy-lc-oxygen-sensor-interface-electronics/)
- Modbus RTU, 9600/8-N-1
- [User Guide](https://www.sstsensing.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/UG-004_OXY-LC-User-Guide.pdf) (section 7.1.2.1 contains set of input registers)
- Device is plugged into Windows machine that I run this Python script

**Packages**

I am using Python 3.6 on Windows 10.

```py
pyserial==3.4
modbus-tk==1.1.0
```

---

****EDIT 1****

Per @Brits comment, I updated my registry addresses to be correct function codes and data frame addresses.

****EDIT 2****

Updated question since I am getting a different error after more correct library usage.

Comment: Modbus addressing can be a bit confusing. 0x7543 (30019) translates to function code 3 (READ_HOLDING_REGISTERS) register 18 (decimal - data frame address is 0 based) when used with most libraries (have not used modbus-tk but as you pass the function seperatly I strongly suspect this is the issue) More info on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modbus#Coil,_discrete_input,_input_register,_holding_register_numbers_and_addresses) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56428678/need-help-using-modbus-tk-library)

Comment: Okay thank you for pointing that out @Brits!  I was indeed a bit confused.  I have corrected the problem and edited the question.  I am still getting the same `ModbusInvalidResponseError`, any other ideas?

Comment: I was thinking that I am not making a Modbus slave, so I removed that portion from my question.  Now I'm getting a `ModbusError`.  See the traceback in question for more details

Comment: Exception code 3 is "Illegal Data Value" (meaning something with the request is invalid). Since I have not used modbus-tk its difficult to comment too much but would suggest trying ```logger.info(master.execute(1, cst.READ_HOLDING_REGISTERS, 18, 1))``` (modified from the example code). I suspect an issue might be that the last param, quantity_of_x, defaults to 0. This param becomes the 'Quantity of Registers'  in the modbus request packet; 0 is invalid for that (a request to get no registers).

Comment: Hello @Brits!  Thank you again for circling back, you were indeed correct!!  I read the source close more closely, and I realized it the `quantity_of_x` parameter should not be left as the default value of `0`.  I wonder why a default was specified in the library, if it won't ever work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was a lack of understanding of the `Master.execute` method.  I did not realize that the `quantity_of_x` parameter needed to be made non-zero.  A special thanks to @Brits for helping point out several key problems I had with my original code.

When the arg `function_code == defines.READ_INPUT_REGISTERS`, `quantity_of_x` means the amount of `H` (C type, unsigned short, length = 2-byte = 16-bit, [source](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/struct.html#format-characters)) to read ([source code `modbus.py`, line 138](https://github.com/ljean/modbus-tk/blob/5d6b76ad43ee1cde608c2f9a350c2d8cc97857ef/modbus_tk/modbus.py#L138)).

Since the device's data type for the `year_of_manuf` register is 16-bit unsigned integer, the correct change was to add `quantity_of_x=1` as an argument.

Functional Input:

```py
logger.info(
    modbus_master.execute(
        slave=SLAVE_NUM,
        function_code=cst.READ_INPUT_REGISTERS,
        starting_address=year_of_manuf.address,
        quantity_of_x=1,
    )
)
```

Output:

```py
2020-01-21 18:42:05,520 DEBUG   modbus.execute  MainThread      -> 1-4-0-18-0-1-145-207
2020-01-21 18:42:05,560 DEBUG   modbus.execute  MainThread      <- 1-4-2-7-227-250-137
2020-01-21 18:42:05,562 INFO    <ipython-input-1-2d4d0280e33d>.<module> MainThread      (2019,)
```